# Cut some parts of urls in Wordpress (.htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress website and would like to cut parts of my urls like so:

https://example.com/service/test/anything-appear_here/what-i-want-to-keep/

to

https://example.com/what-i-want-to-keep/

I tried a lot of things like :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^service/test/(.*) /$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The best I got is to put down my website ...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The URL edits in WordPress are done within the permalinks options. Go to WP > Settings > Permalinks and adjust them from there.

Ensure that you are able to save your permalinks, if you see an error saying it is not saved contact your hosting provider.